# Setting an individual property of on an object

Tags: javascript, class, object, javascript-objects

I have a class which sets the error an an object

one of the methods does this via a record method

```
  record(errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
      }
```

This accepts an object and sets the value. Typically I would get the errors like so

[image]

But what I am trying to do in put an individual error into the object

`this.errors.record(this.errors.errors.username = {username: "this is my custom error"}`);

However the result was the whole object is overwritten

[image]

How do I change one value in this object?

Comment: If it's the `record` function you show it kind of answers itself; whatever is passed in is what is set to `this.errors`.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to *merge* the object you're passing in with the object that's already there, you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to do that:

```
record(errors) {
    Object.assign(this.errors, errors);
}
```

That copies all of the "own" properties of `errors` to the pre-existing `this.errors` object.

If `this.errors` may not exist, you can add a guard and assignment:

```
record(errors) {
    this.errors = Object.assign(this.errors || {}, errors);
}
```

`Object.assign` returns its first argument. When `this.errors` doesn't exist (well, results in any falsy value), the new object `{}` will be used and returned, and then assigned to `this.errors`. But when `this.errors` exists (results in a truthy value), that one will be used and the assignment is a no-op.

---

`Object.assign` was added relatively recently, but is trivial to polyfill for older environments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my custom error is now in using this.errors.record(this.errors.errors = { username: ["this is my custom error"] }); however the rest of the errors still get wiped.

Comment: @LeBlaireau - Yes, you don't want the assignment in there. Just `this.errors.record({ username: "..."});` Naturally, assigning to `this.errors.errors` will overwrite what used to be there.

Comment: Thanks the problem I am having now is is not being able to  check the value of 
a property I know has a value console.log(this.errors.email); //undefined